# How to open a redirect link in my app without redirecting to external link?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, webview, redirect

I have the following code (AJS + Cordova):

```css
$scope.update = function () {
        myService.update()
          .then(function (response) {
            
            $scope.result = response.data;//prints [Object object]
            console.log("Success!..." +  response.data + "result.." + $scope.result); 

            angular.forEach($scope.result, function(value, key){
               
                console.log(key + ': ' + value); //prints success:true
               
               // $location.url(""+urlToGo);
                $window.location.href = urlToGo;
            })
          }, 
          function (error) {
            $scope.status = 'Unable toget resposne ' + error;
          });

        
      };
```

Here,  $window.location.href = urlToGo; will open a new window in mobile browser, which means user will leave my app. So, is there any technique, I can handle it inside my app using Angular or Cordova, without showing browser to him?

Comment: Hopefully this link should help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36948337/angular-marked-and-inappbrowser-opening-all-links-in-the-system-browser

Answer (score 1):

The following Link helped me resolve this issue for my Cordova App.

[Phonegap - How to open external link inside the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15737582/phonegap-how-to-open-external-link-inside-the-app)

Briefly from that post:

```
var onInApp = window.open('http://paymentpage.com', '_blank', 'location=no,hidden=yes,closebuttoncaption=Done,toolbar=no');
```

I did have to play with the settings dependant upon the platform to get the correct result.

The latest Cordova Docs explain it much better :

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/index.html

Hopefully this will point you in the correct direction.

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try!

Comment: Is it secure to do for Payment?

Comment: The window you open is an external hyperlink and is secure as the site you are opening. Your communicating with that site will be the only potential security risk from within your app.